# html - invalid value of multi input radio button

Tags: python, html, radio-button

I have multi input type radio buttons on my page and when I submitted it, on the server side, that two values are exchanged, I have no idea how to debug it.

So here my code,

```
<div id="is_partial_time" class="form-group">
   <label class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 control-label" for="is_partial_time">Would you accept a CDD or a replacement contract</label>
       <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-8">
          <div id="group_is_partial_time" class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
              <label class="btn btn-info">
                  <input type="radio" name="is_partial_time" value="true"/>Yes
              </label>
              <label class="btn btn-info active">
                   <input type="radio" name="is_partial_time" value="false" checked="checked"/>No
              </label>
          </div>
      </div>
</div>

<div id="is_replacement_contract" class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 control-label" for="is_replacement_contract">Would you accept a partial time?</label>
       <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-8">
           <div id="group_is_replacement_contract" class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
               <label class="btn btn-info">
                   <input type="radio" name="is_replacement_contract" value="true"/>Yes
               </label>
               <label class="btn btn-info active">
                   <input type="radio" name="is_replacement_contract" value="false" checked="checked"/>No
               </label>
          </div>
       </div>
 </div>
```

Example,

on the web form ():

I choose:

*Would you accept a replacement contract?* ***Yes***

*Would you accept a partial time?* ***No***

On the server side:

*Would you accept a replacement contract?* ***No***

*Would you accept a partial time?* ***Yes***

Info: I'm using python Flask.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `<label ..>` are at the wrong place. It should be

```
<div id="is_partial_time" class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 control-label" for="is_partial_time">Would you accept a partial time?</label>
       <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-8">
          <div id="group_is_partial_time" class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
              <label class="btn btn-info">
                  <input type="radio" name="is_partial_time" value="true"/>Yes
              </label>
              <label class="btn btn-info active">
                   <input type="radio" name="is_partial_time" value="false" checked="checked"/>No
              </label>
          </div>
      </div>
</div>

<div id="is_replacement_contract" class="form-group">
   <label class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 control-label" for="is_replacement_contract">Would you accept a CDD or a replacement contract</label>
       <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-8">
           <div id="group_is_replacement_contract" class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
               <label class="btn btn-info">
                   <input type="radio" name="is_replacement_contract" value="true"/>Yes
               </label>
               <label class="btn btn-info active">
                   <input type="radio" name="is_replacement_contract" value="false" checked="checked"/>No
               </label>
          </div>
       </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Hi moose, thanks for quick response. which <label ..>? because I don't see the different both your code suggestion with my code. Thanks

Comment: ah yeah, you're right, thank you, thank you :) Javier and moose